# Adding a div to a filmstrip carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a div that contains a picture and a small description on each cat photo. Creating the div isn't the hard part, it's making it attached to that specific image, so that when the image gets switched with another, the div gets switched along with it. I want it to be responsive and specific for each photo and not stand in a fixed position.

http://jsfiddle.net/benknowles/TUwqn/2/

```
 <div class="red">

 <div class="red-content col-md-4" style="background-color: red;">
    Content goes here.

 </div>


 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the carousel you're using? Also, why don't you just composite the cat picture and your picture together in Photoshop/GIMP rather than create a second image?

Comment: I'm experimenting with java script and bootstrap and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work as a separate image

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Image caption like this are a thing of the past, I have done something bit more appealing on the eyes. Principle is the same.

The main picture is positioned relative, the caption is positioned absolute in what you want.

```
.profiles > li { width:150px; height:200px; float:left; margin-right:50px; }
.info, .pic { position:absolute; }
```

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/ALmrja